# Symfony2 - Login check password

Tags: php, symfony

I have a custom user provider in which I retrieve the password from a database. This password is based on a `text+username`.

In **Symfony** `login_check` process, I'd like that the password field equals to the input text in this `password field` + the input text in the `username field`, and not only based on the input text in the password field.

Is there a way to do that ?

In short, I'd like to force symfony to check if password defined in the User Provider equals to `_password` field + `_username` field

Answer (score 1):

Todo that you will need to also right a custom authentication provider. You can look through the doc here to do that:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Basically clone the default one and add your changes to the password checker.

You may also be able to accomplish it by doing as the custom user provider docs suggest:

> If your external users have their passwords salted via a different method, then you'll need to do a bit more work so that Symfony properly encodes the password. That is beyond the scope of this entry, but would include sub-classing MessageDigestPasswordEncoder and overriding the mergePasswordAndSalt method.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html

It seems like you may be using the username field as a salt of sorts so that may be simpler to accomplish then writing a full custom authentication